# Whats the meaning of this nativequery?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, nativequery

When I read my colleague codes I found these codes cannot understand.

This is jpa nativequery and deleted function

```
StringBuilde
```

I want to know just query part.

```
select u.id, u.username,
if(u.id = loginuserId, true, false) equalUserState,
if((select true from follow where fromUserId = loginuserId and toUserId = u.id), true, false) as followState
from follow f inner join user u on f.toUserId = u.id
and f.fromUserId = pageUserId
```

In these codes

```
if(u.id = loginuserId, true, false) equalUserState,
if((select true from follow where fromUserId = loginuserId and toUserId = u.id), true, false) as followState
```

I Can't understand these parts.

How can i translate into SQL query?

And Whats that meaning?

Thank you

Comment: *How can i translate into SQL query?* it is an sql query

Comment: consider this SQL `select if(month(now()) = 10, "we are in October", "Not in October");`  The `if` statement acts like an if-else statement

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thank you for your example. but i still cannot understand second statement "if((select true from follow) " means "select "true" data in follow table"? if that so where is the column name? I cannot found true column in DB. Im so confused ....

Comment: looks strange, maybe the code changed but now they want to hard-code as true.

Comment: It's checking to see if a row exists in `follow` where the `fromUserId` and `toUserId` match `loginuserid` and `u.id` respectively.  If there is such a row, then `followState` will come out true; if not, then `followState` will come out false.  Here, `true` is not a column name, it's a constant.

Comment: @ScaryWombat *Is it because of the inner join ?* of course, no. Your queries have no INNER JOIN in theis texts. The last query returns empty rowset because none row matches WHERE condition.

Comment: @Akina Yes I know that **my** query does not have an inner join, but the OP's does.  In the previous comment it was written *If there is such a row, then followState will come out true; if not, then followState will come out false.*  However my query shows that if there is no row returned then the value will be empty **not** `false` - Are we on the same page?

Comment: @ScaryWombat You should ask not about JOIN but about correlated subquery I think...

Comment: @akina - right, thinking about it, an inner join would have the opposite effect (I think).  BTW, do you know the answer?

Comment: @ScaryWombat The query in question does not contain table alias for the most part of the columns. And OP have not provided CREATE TABLE for used tables. So I can only predict... the only thing which I can say - even if this query is logically correct (I see potential "rowset instead of scalar" problem at least) it is not optimal.